# Merging nearby duplicate values only in an array with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have an array which is generated from `$('.player').each(function()` which looks like this :

```
["foo"]
["foo"]
["bar"]
["bar"]
["bar"]
["foo"]
["somethingelse"]
```

I'd want this array to merge the nearby values only (the first two `foo`s but not the last one since there are no `foo`s above and below its index):

```
["foo"]
["bar"]
["foo"]
["somethingelse"]
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction on how to merge duplicate values (if near the same value) within an array?

So far, the only thing I have is this, but sadly it merges values no matter what indexes they are at.

```
var uniqueNames = [];
$.each(fruits, function(i, el){
    if($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(el);
});
console.log(uniqueNames);
```

EDIT : 
Thank you your codes work flawlessly. Just for my knowledge, what if I wanted the two foos to be merged and renamed (as foo2) ?

Comment: `var uniqueNames = fruits.filter((value,index,array) => !index || value !== array[index-1]);`

Comment: @Thomas, this is a correct answer

Comment: My gosh, it works. You've saved me an headache. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with straight-forward, pure JS in `O(N)` as follows:

```js
var RemoveDuplicates = function(arr){
  if(arr.length<2)               //Array is too short to have duplicates
    return arr
  var ret = [arr[0]]             //First item cannot be a duplicate
  for(var i=1;i<arr.length;i++){ //Loop over all other items
    if(arr[i-1]!=arr[i])         //If previous item is the same, ignore this item
      ret.push(arr[i]);          //Previous item was different, so keep current
  }
  return ret;
}

arr = ["foo","foo","bar","bar","bar","foo","somethingelse"]
arr = RemoveDuplicates(arr)
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may do as follows with pure JS

```js
var arrs = [["foo"],["foo"],["bar"],["bar"],["bar"],["foo"],["somethingelse"]],
  result = arrs.reduce((p,c,i,a) => i ? c[0] !== a[i-1][0] ? (p.push(c),p) : p
                                      : (p.push(c),p),[]);
console.log(result);
```